# Pandas string reassignment errors when read from csv but not xlsx

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string, csv

I'm using pandas to read in two datasets and reassign the `value` column of each. One dataset is a csv, loaded with `pd.read_csv()`, and the other is xlsx, loaded with `Workbook.sheets()` from the sxl library.

Before reassignment, both value columns are string datatype (checked with `df.dtypes`). I reassign the value column like so:

```py
df["value"] = df["value"].replace({"A": 0, "B": 1})
```

This line errors for the data from the csv with

```
ValueError: Cannot set non-string value '0' into a StringArray.
```

I get the similar error

```
ValueError: Cannot set non-string value 'True' into a StringArray
```

when I try to reassign a string type column to True/False. There's no error when I run the same line on the value column of the data from the excel document.

I can fix the error for myself by casting the value before reassignment with `.astype('object')`, and I'm unsure why this works -- `value` in both dataframes is string type.

My colleague doesn't get the error, so that band-aid may not be necessary. I'm running Python 3.9.4, pandas version 1.5.3, and numpy version 1.22.0.

Comment: What versions of `python`, `panda` and `numpy` is your colleague running? You could always declare the `dtype` on the `read_csv` call. Something like this: `pd.read_csv(file, dtype=np.object)`

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, the dtype of `"value"` column is `'string'`, which is an [extension dtype for string data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html) that is also nullable. That means the values in this column can be either a string or NaN. When you try to replace values in this column into integers (`"A" -> 0` and `"B" -> 1`), that's raising the error because, well, the values in this column cannot be integers.

The following code reproduces this error:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']}, dtype='string')
df["value"] = df["value"].replace({"A": 0, "B": 1})               # <------ error
```

If the replacement values are strings, there will be no errors, i.e., the following doesn't raise any errors:

```py
df["value"] = df["value"].replace({"A": '0', "B": '1'})           # <------ no error
```

#### Why doesn't `dtype=object` raise any errors?

Pandas object dtype can hold any Python object, in other words, anything goes in a column with object dtype. Python objects such as integers, strings, floats, even lists, dictionaries, etc. may be stored in an `object` column. So in such a column, replacing strings with integers works without a hitch.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C']}, dtype=object)
df1["value"] = df1["value"].replace({"A": 0, "B": 1})             # <------ no error
```

However, in that case, the column becomes a mixed column. To see the values the `'value'` column as Python objects, call `tolist()` on the column.

```py
df['value'].tolist()         # ['0', '1', '0', 'C']         <------ all strings
df1['value'].tolist()        # [0, 1, 0, 'C']               <------ integers and strings
```

Note that `dtype=str` also converts column dtype into `object` (but the values are actually strings), so if the column dtype is changed using e.g. `astype(str)`, then its values can also be replaced by an integer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. Why would the same reassignment not error when the data is read in from an excel document, even though its `value` is string type as well? That's my main question (not the error itself)

Comment: @butterflyeffect check the dtypes of the two frames (`df['value'].dtype` would do). I would suspect (and in fact that's the implicit assumption I made) the string columns from xlsx are read as `object` but the string columns from csv are read as `string`.

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that I checked the data types and they're both string -- that's the weird part!

Comment: can you show the outcome of `df['value'].info()` of both files?